# Dockerize dotnet core 2.2 app, what and why lines are placed in nopCommerce Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, .net-core, devops, nopcommerce

## Questions about dockerizing dotnet core app

As an example I will provide the Dockerfile for nopCommercew
https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/Dockerfile

Everything is clear except the following:

```
RUN dotnet publish Nop.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app/published
...
# add globalization support
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

WORKDIR /app        
RUN mkdir bin
RUN mkdir logs  
                                                            
COPY --from=build /app/published .
```

1. Why should the app be published to `/app/published`, then copy it to the `/app`?
2. Why `--from=build` is used in line `COPY --from=build /app/published .`?
3. What is this line `RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs` is used for? and why should it be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker image is bunch of smaller layers.

The `docker build .` creates multiple small docker images at each logical step and caches it. Check docker build output closely and look for `Using cache` in the output.

check the output of

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 docker images docker inspect <image id of mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1>`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#The Answer
There are two `FROM` docker commands.
The first command points to the `.NET Core SDK` which is probably 600 MB.

The second command points to `.NET Core runtime` which is probably 200 MB.

SDK images are for developers to build/test/package. It supports all the `dotnet` CLI commands are available here. Such as `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`.

Runtime images are optimized for production. They are smaller and hence faster.

For an efficient build process docker suggests working with multiple images. SDK and runtime.

###1: Why should the app be published to /app/published, then copy it to the /app?

The `dotnet publish` command is of the SDK image cycle. `/app/publish` has everything required to run your application but on the SDK image.

We need to take this to the runtime image.

WORKDIR /app creates a folder in the runtime image.

###2: Why --from=build is used in line COPY --from=build /app/published .?

After the above steps the output of the publish command is available on SDK docker image in the /app/publish folder.

We called it "build" on the first line of Dockerfile by passing `AS build` at the end of the command

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build`

with `--from==build` we point to the SDK image and copy it to the runtime image. That's for communication between two docker images.

###3: What is this line RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs is used for? and why should it be used?

The apk is for the installation of packages on the Linux OS. Think of it as equivalent to nuget of .net.

`icu-libs` is a Linux package for Unicode characters.

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/icu-libs
I am assuming that nopCommerce supports the Unicode characters.
The `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1` installs a Debian Linux probably version 4 which does not have Unicode support.
through APK command nopCommerce is installing it manually.

Comment: I have one more concern regarding the following two lines `RUN mkdir bin RUN mkdir logs` Why should we have them in place?

Comment: Dockerfile is a set of instructions to docker engine. These instructions can do a lot of things. like `COPY` from your local computer to inside docker images. `RUN` runs a command inside docker. these two run commands are creating folders. `mkdir` is the linux command for creating director.  to tell Docker to run `mkdir` inside docker linux container Dockerfile command is `RUN` so collective effect is a folder is created inside docker.